# Health Check for a Web Url

Tags: url, web, ping, health-monitoring

I'm trying to implement a "health check" for my web site, basically want to write some code in java or use some freeware that can keep pinging my website url every 10 mins and see if it's up and available, if it's down for some reason would like to log that to a log file (or send an email etc).

I did search in net but didn't get any specific implementation for this, pls suggest if you know any.

Please note - my cloud provider does not provide such a feature as I have only a trail license with them, so this will be something like a temp arrangement till we move into the professional mode with the cloud provider.

Comment: Just learn to make HTTP requests in your favorite language; it's as simple as that.

Comment: did you tried existing solutions: https://www.google.com/search?q=site+availability+monitor ?

Comment: Andre and msangel - we finally went with monitor.us, they provide a free and quick way to keep monitoring url health that way we dont have to implement a custom solution. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily put something together for this in Java

Hit your URL with the java.net API like so

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.nonexistent.com/");
URL url = uri.toURL();
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

which will throw an exception if the site is down.
So put it inside a try/catch block and do what you need to do in the catch. (you can send a mail using the java mail api - just do a google to find enough examples)

And finally you can make this run according to a schedule using java.util.Timer API.

Will leave the specifics up to you to figure out :)

Comment: Thanks, I didnt try this one but I know that this kind will work, basically as this was an interim solution, we wanted to go with some product already out in market...